# Vector3 value assignation seems ignored

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

Working on Unity 5.6.2f1, Android 4.3.
Searched 6 hours without understanding so far, still probably a reference/value misunderstanding of mine, help greatly needed.

```
    float nx = pose.Get<AndroidJavaObject>("tx").Call<float>("floatValue");
    Debug.Log("nx type is " + nx.GetType() + " and value is " + nx);
    float testZ = 3;
    Debug.Log("testZ type is " + testZ.GetType() + " and value is " + testZ);
    Vector3 otherPosition = new Vector3(nx, 2.2f, testZ);
    Debug.Log("otherPosition type is " + otherPosition.GetType() + " and value is " + otherPosition);
```

The corresponding logs gives :

I/Unity   (18922): nx type is System.Single and value is 0.0325

I/Unity   (18922): testZ type is System.Single and value is 3

I/Unity   (18922): otherPosition type is UnityEngine.Vector3 and value is (0.0, 2.2, 3.0)

---

More informations on pose :

```
AndroidJavaObject pose = display.Get<AndroidJavaObject>("pose");
```

And

```
pose.Get<AndroidJavaObject>("tx")
```

should return a Java Float object.

Already tried to declare nx as a private float member of my script, nothing changes.

I don't have any idea left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Actually... Everything's fine.

When you call `Debug.Log(vector3Obj)`, that invokes `Vector3#ToString()`.  This is normal.

*However* the ToString override of Vector3 *rounds its floating point values to the nearest 0.1.* This is what's causing your problem: `0.0325` is rounded down to "0.0" and that's why you're getting the result you're getting in the debug output.  The vector3 object is still holding the value of 0.0325, but that that value is *too small* to be distinguished from 0 when converted to a string in `Vector3#ToString()`.

Try this:

```
Debug.Log("otherPosition type is " + otherPosition.GetType()
  + " and value is " + (otherPosition*10));
```

Comment: *Self shot myself* Indeed. Thank you Draco, amazing speed answer too.

Comment: @J.Jacobs-VP Eh, the speed was only because I navigated to the new questions list, saw your question, and went "oh, I know what this is." Glad to help :)